# HtmlAgilityPack - Wait for javascript to run

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get info off of a webpage using the HtmlAgilityPack in c#. My issue is that the page I'm trying to get info from loads a preliminary static page and then updates it with a .js script a few seconds later.

Is it possible to make HtmlAgilityPack wait for the .js script to do its thing before saving and parsing through the HTML code?

Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: htmlagilitypack will not process javascript

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is designed for parsing HTML. It is not a browser. You'll want to look into browser automation tools instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White, that would be why I asked if there was a better alternative.

Comment: @Llama, do you have any suggestions? I've never used those types of tools before.

Comment: The ones I know of are: Selenium, Puppeteer.